# How to inverse the degree order in poly1d

Tags: python

The Python function poly1d generates a polynomial in descending degree (from upper degree to zero degree). How to inverse this order, ie. generate a polynomial in ascending order (from zero upward)?

Comment: There is no such function in the built-in scope. Provide the proper module where you get such a function.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using NumPy. The older `poly1d` function does indeed take the coefficients in decreasing order. I suppose you could slice them backwards if you have them in increasing order:

```
In [6]: import numpy as np
In [7]: coeffs = [-2, 4, 3]
In [8]: p1 = np.poly1d(coeffs[::-1])
```

There is another, better, NumPy module called [`Polynomial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html) which takes its coefficients in increasing order:

```
In [9]: p2 = np.polynomial.Polynomial(coeffs)
```

For reasons of numerical stability, the `Polynomial` class distinguishes between the *window* and *domain* of the polynomial: read the documentation carefully before doing anything advanced with this class...